# JSONP http request gives 404 in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jsonp, mailchimp

I have been working with mailchimp integration into angular application and for using it in pure JS, I have got the code from embedded form in mailchimp site and the code as follows,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&amp;id=01681f1b55" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <h2>Subscribe</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d_01681f1b55" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[3]='ADDRESS';ftypes[3]='address';fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';fnames[5]='BIRTHDAY';ftypes[5]='birthday';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

The above code works fine and no issues.. The same thing needs to be included in angular application for which my try as follows,

**Reference** I took: https://gist.github.com/inorganik/846c52550db97454646054270e4f1270

And the implementation as follows,

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

interface MailChimpResponse {
  result: string;
  msg: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
submitted = false;
  mailChimpEndpoint =
    'https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&amp;id=01681f1b55';
  error = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  userForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [
           Validators.required,
            Validators.email,
        ]),
    });
  }

  subscribeEmail() {
    this.error = '';


        if (this.userForm.controls.email.status === 'VALID') {

      const params = new HttpParams()
                .set('EMAIL', this.userForm.controls.email.value)
      console.log(params);
            const mailChimpUrl = this.mailChimpEndpoint + params.toString();

            this.http.jsonp<MailChimpResponse>(mailChimpUrl, 'callback').subscribe(response => {
        console.log('response ', response)
                if (response.result && response.result !== 'error') {
                    this.submitted = true;
                }
                else {
                    this.error = response.msg;
                }
            }, error => {
                console.error(error);
                this.error = 'Sorry, an error occurred.';
            });
        }
  }
}
```

[**Working Stackblitz here ..**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsonp-gfzdr1)

My requirement is the above code which works in the snippet doesn't work in angular application and it results in **404** error..

Please take a look at network/console tab in developer tool which gives 404..

Also I could notice that the param which I pass in to the url doesn't reflect in query param of network call..

Please help me to implement the same api url which works in click of subscribe button to be working in angular application as well.

Take a look at stackblitz please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsonp-gfzdr1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the parameters properly.  Here is a working example that will send the request.  It does still return an error, but it is a response from MailChimp that you have processed too many records.

Working Version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsonp-1qquhy

Answer (score 0):

after url add &
example this is you url:- https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&id=01681f1b55

here add & symbol here
https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&id=01681f1b55&

and working stackblitz url is below

working version:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsonp-96dmvh

Comment: You  cannot judge that yourself. The answer which was most helpful to OP they can "accept", which causes the green tick. Other answers are voted upon. Commenting like you did on your own post is only an opinion and an obviously biased opintion at that. An answer is good, if it has explnation of how it works and why it is supposed to help. An answer can more easily be recognised as good, if the formatting is appropriate ( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) and otherwise follows [answer].